# Set Yup validation for attribute of Yup array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, validation, yup

I want to set validation for number attribute in Yup array of objects, such that

1. weight of each object must be >=0 and <=100 in array.
2. Sum of weights of all objects in array also must be less than 100.

```js
const ParamValidator = Yup.object()
         .shape({
         params: Yup.array()
            .of(
                Yup.object()
                    .shape({
                        name: Yup.string.max(30).required(),
                        weight: Yup.number().min(0).max(100).required(),
                    })
                    .required(),
            )
            .required()
```

However I figured out, I can make point (1.) with min & max for individual object's weight, but not able to do (2.) that how can I put and check sum of all object's weight.
***Only use Yup Validation***

Answer (score -1):

```
    const ParamValidator = Yup.object()
     .shape({
     params: Yup.array()
        .of(
            Yup.object()
                .shape({
                    name: Yup.string.max(30).required(),
                    weight: Yup.number().min(0).max(100).required(),
                })
                .required(),
        )
        .required()
        .test('params',
              'sum of weights of all objects of params should be <= 100',
              (values: any[]) => values.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.weight, 0) <= 100,)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).